# Integral of Brownian motion over $[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Define $$ Y \equiv \int_0^1 \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}} ds$$  I want to calculate the mean and variance of $Y$ but I'm not sure if I've done it correctly:

The mean is fairly easy: $$E(Y) = \int \int_0^1 \frac{B_s(\omega)}{\sqrt{s}} ds dP(\omega) = \int_0^1 \int\frac{B_s(\omega)}{\sqrt{s}} dP(\omega) ds = 0$$ where we may exchange integrals by Fubini's theorem noting that $E|B_s| = \sqrt{2s/\pi}$

The variance is where I'm confused.  We know that by Ito's lemma $$\sqrt{t}B_t = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}} + \int_0^t\sqrt{s}dB_s$$

There is no quadratic variation term since $\sqrt{t}$ is FV.  Set $t = 1$ to obtain $$Y/2 = B_1 - \int_0^1 \sqrt{s} dB_s = \int_0^1 (1- \sqrt{s}) dB_s $$  so by Ito isometry we get $$E(Y^2) = 4 \int_0^t (1-\sqrt{s})^2 ds $$

I'm flat out too lazy to do the integral and finish this, but I just want to double check that I'm doing this question correctly.  Thanks if you can confirm!

Comment: An elementary approach: Use Riemann sums and compute their variance using the fact that $E(B_sB_t)=\min \{t,s\}$.

Comment: Your approach is fine.  And the final integral isn't difficult or even very tedious.

Comment: Thanks.  I know it's not difficult, that's primarily why I just left it.